# Creating a new list from elements of an other list, referencing the elements of the latter

Tags: python, list

I want to create a new list from a previous one's elements, but without copying them. That is what happens:

```
In [23]: list = range(10)

In [24]: list2 = list[0:4]

In [25]: list
Out[25]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

In [26]: list2
Out[26]: [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Though the elements of the lists seem to have the same id,

```
In [29]: id(list[1])
Out[29]: 145137840

In [30]: id(list2[1])
Out[30]: 145137840
```

After editing one element, I don't change the object that is referenced, but the value for that site on the list.

```
In [31]: list[1] = 100

In [32]: id(list[1])
Out[32]: 145138628

In [33]: id(list2[1])
Out[33]: 145137840

In [34]: list
Out[34]: [0, 100, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

In [35]: list2
Out[35]: [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

I want to use the list2 as a representative of some particular elements of list. I'm guessing that there should be a good way to compose a list that gives me the chance to edit the values of the elements of list, when I also change the value for list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anywhere `1` or another small number is in a variable, it will always have the same id. These numbers only exist once, and since they're immutable, it's safe for them to be referenced everywhere.

Using slice syntax `[:]` always makes a copy.

When you set `list1[1]`, you're not changing the value of what's stored in memory, you're pointing `list1[1]` to a new location in memory. So since you didn't point `list2[1]` to a different location, it still points to the old location and value.

Never name a variable `list` since there is a built in function by that name.

If you want to do what you're talking about with minimal modification, try:

```
list1 = [[x] for x in range(10)]
list2 = list1[:4]
list1[1][0] = 100
print list2
```

You just need to always add [0] after the item you want to reference. As the lists don't get replaced, just the item in them, and `list2` points to the list not the item, it will stay in sync.

Comment: Oh, you're right.
But then is there a way that I can reach and change the value taht both of these lists were pointing before.
Should I for example, store the id's for each object, and then reach them via their ids?
It doesn't seem to be an elegant solution, though.

Comment: You don't really ever change values in Python, you just create a new value and point to that instead. Try storing a list of indexes (so list2 would be `[0, 1, 2, 3]` -- this is a bad example because your values and their indexes are the same) and looking them up like `list1[list2[0]]`.

Answer (score 1):

Use mutable types as list elements. For example:

```
>>> a = [[1], [2]]
>>> b = a[1]
>>> a
[[1], [2]]
>>> b
[2]
>>> b[0]=[3]
>>> a
[[1], [[3]]]
>>> b
[[3]]
>>>
```